# Function of sodium amalgam and CO2 in formation of aldohexose

Tags: reaction-mechanism, biochemistry, organic-reduction

There is this following conversion in my book:

> $$\gamma-\text{Lactone}\ce{->[Na/Hg +CO2]}\text{Aldohexose}$$

I'm not sure how this reaction takes place. I searched for mechanisms and couldn't find one.What's the function of CO2? Any help is appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's a reducing agent. Does this help? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119881/fischers-proof-of-the-structure-of-glucose/121294#121294

Comment: I couldn't find a detailed mechanism for this specific reaction. Also what is the function of CO2?

Comment: CO2 is likely a buffer. The reaction probably gives overreduction of the aldehyde to an alcohol with simple lactones. A 2-electron reduction of the carbonyl group followed by protonation from solvent leads to a hydroxy aldehyde, some of which survives further reduction by forming the intramolecular hemiacetal. I’m sure the rxn is insufficient but Fischer only need some product to prove his point.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. CO2 is probably a buffer because the reaction is carried out at round 3-5 ph. Thanks!

Comment: I meant inefficient, not insufficient. ;)

Comment: I guessed it. No probs!